# Proving $\cos(z)$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> I am trying to determine whether or not $\cos(z)$ is holomorphic on the complex plane.

So basically I have written $$\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}.$$

But when I expand and get to the Cauchy Riemann equations the test for $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
it fails as $$-\sin(x)(e^y + e^{-y}) \neq \sin(x)(e^y - e^{-y})$$

However a little bird told me that $\cos(z)$ should be holomorphic but I can't figure out where the error is.  I will probably try expanding $\cos$ using hyperbolic trig but I want to do it this way.

Comment: Wait in your definition, you wrote down the function as a sum of two holomorphic functions, isn't that enough?

Comment: Sum of analytic functions is also analytic :)

Comment: use the Taylor series for $\cos$ or $\exp$, show they have $\infty$ radius of convergence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

• Let $z=x+iy$. Then
$$e^{iz}=e^{ix-y}=e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))$$

• The real part $u$ of $\cos(\cdot)$ is then $$\Re\left(\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right) =
\dfrac{e^{-y}\cos(x) + e^y\cos(-x)}{2}=
\dfrac{e^{-y}\cos(x) + e^y\cos(x)}{2}$$

so that 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\sin(x)\dfrac{e^{-y}+e^y}{2}$$

• The imaginary part $v$ $\cos(\cdot)$ is then $$\Im\left(\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}\right) =
\dfrac{e^{-y}\sin(x) + e^y\sin(-x)}{2}
=\dfrac{e^{-y}\sin(x) - e^y\sin(x)}{2}$$

so that 
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \sin(x)\dfrac{-e^{-y}-e^y}{2}$$

Therefore 
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}}$$

• I let you verify the other equation. Moreover, $u$ and $v$ are differentiable, so that $\cos(\cdot)$ is holomorphic.

---

• Alternatively, you know that $z \mapsto iz$ and $z \mapsto -iz$ are holomorphic, and that $z \mapsto e^z$ is holomorphic (it is defined by a Taylor series). But the composition of holomorphic maps is also holomoprhic! Then, $z \mapsto e^{±iz}$ are holomorphic. So is their sum, and multiplying by a constant preserves the holomorphy.

Comment: Thank you, Apparently my mind cannot preform basic calculus this evening!!

Answer (score 3):

By your definition, and with $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$:

$$\cos z=\frac12\left(e^{ix-y}+e^{-ix+y}\right)=\frac12\left(e^{-y}(\cos x+i\sin x)+e^y(\cos x-i\sin x)\right)=$$$${}$$

$$=\overbrace{\cos x\cosh y}^{=u(x,y)}+i\overbrace{\left(-\sin x\sinh y\right)}^{=v(x,y)}\implies$$$${}$$

$$\begin{cases}u_x=-\sin x\cosh y=v_y\\{}\\u_y=\cos x\sinh y=-v_x\end{cases}$$

and  the above is true for *any* complex element $\;z=x+iy\;$ , thus your function's holomorphic.

Comment: Holomorphy is a bit stronger that just the C–R equations. But for instance, if we require moreover $u$ and $v$ to be differentiable, then $u+iv$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @Watson Yes, but that's too much.  In fact, it is enough to require  that the first partial derivatives of $\;u,\,v\;$ exist (not even continuity is needed), together with $\;f\;$ being continuous and the C-R equations to have holomorphy. Yet in this case the partial derivatives existence is trivial, and $\;f\;$ being continuous is trivial, too.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comment your definition of $\cos z$ gives obviously a holomorphic function.
If you start from the definition $ \cos z = \cos (x+iy)$ , then the proof  is also simple using hyperbolic functions:

$$
\cos(x+iy)=\cos x\cos(iy)-\sin x\sin(iy)=\cos x\cosh y -i\sin x \sinh y
$$

so:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-\sin x \cosh y = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
$$
But also your method gives the same result. Note that, for $z=x+iy$, your definition gives:

$$
\cos (x+iy)=\frac {e^{-y}}{2}(\cos x +i \sin x)+\frac {e^{y}}{2}(\cos x-i \sin x)=
$$
$$
\cos x\left(\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2} \right)+i\sin x\left(\frac{-e^y+e^{-y}}{2} \right)=u+iv
$$
so:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-\sin x \left(\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2} \right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-\sin x \left(\frac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2} \right)
$$